# My Application could not parse spring XML bean definition from class path resource

Tags: xml, spring

I'm beginner to spring framework and working on simple console app to display 3 points of triangle with co-ordinates(x,y). when i try to launch, it doesn't parse XML document from class path resource.

```
This is Drawing.java class
package org.test;
```

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Drawing {

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
    Triangle triangle = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
    triangle.draw();

    }

}
```

This is Triangle.java class

```
package org.test;

public class Triangle {

    private Point pointA;
    private Point pointB;
    private Point pointC;

public Point getPointA() {
        return pointA;
    }
    public void setPointA(Point pointA) {
        this.pointA = pointA;
    }
    public Point getPointB() {
        return pointB;
    }
    public void setPointB(Point pointB) {
        this.pointB = pointB;
    }
    public Point getPointC() {
        return pointC;
    }
    public void setPointC(Point pointC) {
        this.pointC = pointC;
    }

    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("PointA = (" +getPointA().getX() + " , " + getPointA().getY() + ")");
        System.out.println("PointB = (" +getPointB().getX() + " , " + getPointB().getY() + ")");
        System.out.println("PointC = (" +getPointC().getX() + " , " + getPointC().getY() + ")");
    }


}
```

This is Point.java class

```
package org.test;

public class Point {

private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }


}
```

This is Spring.xml i.e. XML bean configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "https://www.springframework/dtd/spring-beans-2.0dtd">


<beans>
  <bean id="triangle" class="org.test.Triangle">
    <property name="pointA" ref="ZeroPoint"/>
    <property name="pointB" ref="OnePoint"/>
    <property name="pointC" ref="TwoSPoint"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="ZeropPoint" class="org.test.Point">
    <property name="x" value="0.0"/>
    <property name="y" value="0.0"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="OnePoint" class="org.test.Point">
    <property name="x" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="y" value="1.0"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="TwoPoint" class="org.test.Point">
    <property name="x" value="2.0"/>
    <property name="y" value="2.0"/>
  </bean>
```

When i try to launch this console app following error arise:

```
Sep 04, 2015 10:19:56 AM     org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext     prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1980630: startup date [Fri Sep 04 10:19:56 PKT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
```

Sep 04, 2015 10:19:56 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Spring.xml]

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Spring.xml];                                            nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: www.springframework
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:410)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at org.test.Drawing.main(Drawing.java:11)

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.springframework
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add spring schema and namespaces to `beans` element, like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

Remove `DOCTYPE` completely.

Comment: your welcome, don't forget to vote and accept the answer :)

Comment: @Ali Dehghani

What is the problem with the doctype